# Firebase/Firestore 5.0.3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am using Angular with firebase/firestore and i have an authentication system with the google oauth and everytime when i log in and try to create a document in firestore it deletes it afterwards apparently. The logs say:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.0.3) [Connection]: WebChannel received: {"documentDelete":{"document":"projects/website/databases/(default)/documents/users/Tplww82foIN36hb8mcmSOaAPXbU2","readTime":"2018-05-21T05:35:42.653774Z","removedTargetIds":[2]}}
```

But i executed this code:

```
this.db.doc('users/' + user.uid).set({
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      name: user.displayName,
      photoUrl: user.photoURL,
      roles: {}
    }, {merge: true});
```

Am i missing something obvious? Do i need to provide more logs/code in order to figure this out? Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an easy solution actually: Every observable/promise takes their time, and i signed myself out before it was done creating the documents.